# SQL UNION on 2 table variables where date is same but other data is not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have 2 table variable @Data and @DateTable

@Data conatains the following:

```
Company   Date        Type      Select
Altec    12-1-2010     d           2
Altec    12-1-2010     a           2
Alect   12-3-2010     d            3
```

@DateTable contains the following:

```
Company Date          Type Select
Altec    12-1-2010     a    0
Altec    12-3-2010     a    0
Altec    12-5-2010     a    0
Altec    12-6-2010     a    0
```

I need to have both d and a show up in the same query. So if there is no d that matches the a in the @data table it needs to pull it from the @DateTable.

So basically the results I want are following

```
Company DATE      Type Select
ALTEC   12-1-10     d    2
ALTEC   12-1-10     a    2
ALTEC   12-3-10     d    3
ALTEC   12-3-10     a    0 (This is pulled from @DateTable)
```

How would I Union these 2 tables without getting the ones that are already in the @Data table but also not gettig the extra ones from the @DateType table that dont match.....

Comment: What column(s) are the same between the two tables - `company` and `date`?

Comment: But `type` in your example appears to be pulled from either table.

Comment: +1 for giving an example, despite typos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using EXISTS / NOT EXISTS:

```
 SELECT Company, Date, Type, Select FROM DataTable
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Company, Date, Type, Select FROM DateTable
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DataTable WHERE Company = DateTable.Company AND Date = DateTable.Date)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DataTable WHERE Company = DateTable.Company AND Date = DateTable.Date AND Type = DateTable.Type)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take:

```
SELECT dt.company,
       dt.date,
       COALESCE(d.type, dt.type) AS type,
       COALESCE(d.select, dt.select) AS select
FROM @DateTable dt 
     LEFT JOIN @Data d ON d.company = dt.company
                       AND d.date = dt.date
```

Comment: +1 as it's probably faster than Larry's and more along the lines of what I'd do.  You probably would want a `group by` in there for distinction.  Also, you may need a `where` clause in case there are two records in both tables w/ different `select` values.  Additionally, select should probably also be in double quotes, since it's an sql reserved word.

Comment: maybe `d.company = dt.company and d.date = dt.date and d."select" != dt."select"`

Comment: In the case where the "type" is repeated for the same date and company in each table, wont this SQL include both of them in the results?

Comment: @larry Lustig: COALESCE returns the first non-NULL value, so if both `type` values are not null then the value from the `dt` table will be displayed.

Comment: Sorry, not thinking.  There will only be one row, not two, if the JOIN succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Using Union:

```
select [Company], [Date], [Type], sum([Select]) as [Select]
from (select [Company], [Date], [Type], [Select] from @Data union all
      select [Company], [Date], [Type], [Select] from @DateTable) sq
group by [Company], [Date], [Type]
```